# Create Graph with Angular 5

Tags: graph, frontend, angular5, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to create a graph editor using Angular 5. My goal is to make a DAG editor using a drag/drop feature for nodes and edges, where then I can set some properties on the nodes...

do you know any library I can use to render simple graphs with Angular 5?

Up to now I have only found this lib

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph

nut its documentation is really poor...

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently looking for similar solution as you and this one seems to be best I found so far: https://github.com/Ni55aN/d3-node-editor. There is example specifically for Angular.

There are also paid solutions, such as GoJS, which is amazing, but quite expensive: https://www.nwoods.com/products/gojs/index.html. They have also the Angular implementation.

Comment: The GoJS sample in Angular 4 is at https://github.com/NorthwoodsSoftware/GoJS/tree/master/projects/angular-basic.

Comment: I followed the simple example with angular and I am getting the error: ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_d3_node_editor___default.a.Socket is not a constructor

any help? :)

Comment: That's strange. Do you have all the required dependencies? When I followed this: https://github.com/Ni55aN/D3NE-examples/tree/master/Angular4, I did not run into this problem